# Opening PowerBuilder 6.5 source files in PowerBuilder 11

Tags: powerbuilder

I have some legacy powerbuilder programs I need to take a look at (view the source, layouts, etc), they are from PowerBuilder 6.5. All I have available is PowerBuilder 11 (demo/eval version), and it seems to be unable to open the PBL files (selecting them in the file open dialog does nothing).

I guess that it is because the version is very old. ANyone have any idea how I can view those old source files?

Thanks!

Comment: For those without fear try looking at the PBL in library painter or something and then "edit source" (or export) and take that code and import (or edit source) and paste the code into a recent version of same named object in your new PBL. Not something you'd want to do for an entire application but fine for grabbing/recovering a few objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To view the code in a newer IDE, you'll need to migrate the code (or a copy of the code) to the newer version. Remember there is [no easy backward migration](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/PowerBuilder_Migration/Backward_PowerBuilder_Migratio/backward_powerbuilder_migratio.html), so be careful with the code.

A non-destructive alternative is PBL Peeper ([description](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PBL_Peeper/pbl_peeper.html) and [current version pre-release download](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PreRelease411/setup.exe)). With it you get to view the code for any version, in PBLs or exports, without a need for a PowerBuilder license for the specific version. You get more powerful searching and reporting, but you lose the visual representation of the instantiated objects. However, IMHO, as biased as it may be, it lets you see where scripts are and aren't easier and quicker than the IDE. Plus it's got a bunch of other developer tools like a SQL formatter. And, it's hard to argue with free.

Good luck,

Terry